# How do I get all dates between start date and end date for each task?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

In oracle database, I have a table stored TASK_ID, TASK_START_DATE, TASK_END_DATE.
How do I create a table with each row showing TASK_ID and DATE? (DATE being each day from start til end)

| TASK_ID | TASK_START_DATE | TASK_END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 03-04-2021 | 05-04-2021 |
| 002 | 05-04-2021 | 07-04-2021 |

To

| TASK_ID | DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 03-04-2021 |
| 001 | 04-04-2021 |
| 001 | 05-04-2021 |
| 002 | 05-04-2021 |
| 002 | 06-04-2021 |
| 002 | 07-04-2021 |

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date and time functions are notoriously database dependent.  However, in standard SQL, you can approach this using a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive dates as (
      select TASK_ID, TASK_START_DATE, TASK_END_DATE
      from t
      union all
      select TASK_ID, TASK_START_DATE + INTERVAL '1' DAY, TASK_END_DATE
      from dates
      where TASK_START_DATE < TASK_END_DATE
     )
select task_id, task_start_date
from cte;
```

Note that this suggests and approach.  The specific syntax depends on the database you are using.

Comment: INTERVAL '1 MONTH', - adjust to INTERVAL '1 DAY',

Comment: @irnerd . . . That's fine, but in your question they look like months to me.  You should learn to use YYYY-MM-DD date formats.

Comment: Good that the dates look American format to you - but the question states days (quote  (DATE being each day from start til end) )  - Totally agree with ISO format - but we have a new contributor so lets take simple steps?